# Angular comparing fulldate

Tags: angularjs, date

I am trying to compare `fulldate` in Angular, I am not sure if this is possible.

In my controller I have the date coming in as "mm/dd/yy"

```
$scope.today = $filter('date')(Date.now(), "fullDate");

angular.forEach(courses, function(item) {
            if(item.date === null) { 
                item.date = "";
            } else {
                item.orig = item.date.split('/').join('.');
                item.date = $filter('date')(new Date(item.date), "fullDate");
            }
});
$scope.courses = courses;
```

Then in my HTML I have the following:

```
<someelement ng-if="today >= course.date" />
```

The results are not consistant, i.e the `>=` does not evaluate correctly.

**EDIT:**

Solution is to compare date objects rather than the strings which $filter returns

so :

```
today = new Date();
```

and then create a new date from the string input

```
somedate = new Date(yyyy,mm,dd);
```

Comment: is `course.date` also of the same format?

Comment: Yes, it gets converted to a full date. I found a solution, I think the issue was comparing strings rather than date objects.

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about this is to convert both dates into milliseconds from Jan 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC time. You can use the Date.UTC() method for this.

You can have a look at the documentation for Date.UTC() here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC

So in your case for today's date, you'll do:

```
    var now = new Date;                                            
    $scope.todaysDate = Date.UTC(now.getUTCFullYear(),now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate() , 
  now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds(), now.getUTCMilliseconds());
```

And for a given date:

```
    $scope.givenDate = Date.UTC(givenYear, givenMonth, givenDate);
```

Note here that the givenYear should be in yyyy form and that the givenMonth should be a number from 0 to 11. So January will be 0 and December will be 11. So you'll have to implement a function that does the conversion.

You can get the year, month and date in raw form by doing:

```
    var arr = item.date.split('/');
```

You'll have to convert arr[0], arr[1] and arr[2] into appropriate form and use that as parameters for Date.UTC().

Now that $scope.todaysDate and $scope.givenDate are in milliseconds, you can compare them easily.